# What is a dragonclaw?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, published-adventures, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen

D&D 5e's Hoard of the Dragon Queen has a creature called a "dragonclaw." It's humanoid, and it can apparently be of higher rank than a typical cultist or kobold. However, I am not finding any descriptions of this creature other than simple numeric stats.

What is a dragonclaw? What would it generally look like?

Answer (score 26):

A Dragonclaw is the title for a higher-ranking cultist. You can find the description and stat block in the Monsters Appendix of *Hoard of the Dragon Queen.* (Dragonwings, Dragonfangs, and Dragonsouls are also ever-higher ranking cultists.)

You can find more material on each of the ranks in "Cult Structure" in the introduction of *Rise of Tiamat*. And for a visualization check out either p.71 of *HotDQ* hardcover or p.6 of the *HotDQ* Encounters .pdf.

[image: Dragonclaw Cultist from encounters pdf]

Comment: So, it's a cultist with a more impressive hat.

Comment: @GMJoe  following the well known axiom that the bigger the hat the greater the authorty